# ROR Installation (Heroku Error Push Fail)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, push

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * sqlite3 (= 1.3.5)
       * sass-rails (= 3.2.5)
       * coffee-rails (= 3.2.2)
       * uglifier (= 1.2.3)
       * jquery-rails (= 2.0.2)
       * pg (= 0.12.2)
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
       * jquery-rails
       * sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
       * sqlite3
       * uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you follow the directions in the error message? Some context would be nice. Did it work in the past? What did you change since then?

Comment: Did you `bundle install` && `git commit` before you push ? It appears that your commited Gemfile is different from the one you're trying to push.

Answer (score 1):

As, log is saying:

```
  You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
```

I think you have not commited Gemfile.lock file before pushing to heroku. Run bundle install and then commit both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. After that push code to heroku.

Comment: @nhic0tine: As you are new here, don't forget to accept the answer as right if it solved your problem.